# How to optimise a function with parameters bounds correctly in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, anonymous-function

I'm using Matlab 2015a.

Here is the function I want to optimise:

```
function result = fig_of_merit(x, a, b, c, d) 
    result = 1;
end
```

This is how I want to optimise the function:

```
x1 = [10*10^-6, 120]; 
x2 = [300*10^-6, 175];
fminbnd(@(x) fig_of_merit(x, 1, 2, 3, 4),x1,x2);
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Error using  * 
>   Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in fminbnd (line 291)
>
> x = xf + si * max( abs(d), tol1 );
>
> Error in test (line 5)
>
> fminbnd(@(x) fig_of_merit(x, 1, 2, 3, 4),x1,x2);

What's wrong with my code? I did the same for optimisation without bounds using the *fminsearch* function and everything was fine.

It has something to do with the anonymous function I used - when I reduced the vectors x1 and x2 to scalars, it worked:

```
fminbnd(@(x) fig_of_merit(x, 1, 2, 3, 4),-4, 5);
```

It doesn't satisfy me, because I want to optimise 2 parameters at once.

Comment: You'll have a hard time optimising the constant function:) Anyway, the problem might be solved by `result = ones(size(x));`, I'm not sure.

Comment: Then I got the following error: *User supplied objective function must return a scalar value.*.

Comment: The help for `fminbnd` say "FUN accepts scalar input X and returns a scalar function value F evaluated at X." So it looks like `fminbnd` does not allow for optimizing multiple parameters at once like the other optimization functions.

Comment: Thanks. But does it mean that there is no function in Matlab which optimises a vector function with constraints? It doesn't seem likely - Matlab is a well-developed language. On the other hand, I failed to find any other function which does what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fminbnd` function only works on scalar parameters. It can't optimize two parameters at once. However, the `fmincon` function can do this:

```
x1 = [10*10^-6, 120]; 
x2 = [300*10^-6, 175];
fmincon(@(x) fig_of_merit(x, 1, 2, 3, 4),ones(size(x1)),[],[],[],[],x1,x2);
```